# How to run 2 motors at the same time in the new EV3 version?

Tags: ev3, motor

So I've seen a question that solves my problem in an older version, which I don't think is possible in the *Education EV3 Classroom - 1.2.2,* which is the one I'm using. I want to simultaneously run 2 motors at the same time, but in the post for the older version that I saw, It talked about White Technic Bars which I don't believe is in the version that I am using, so I was wondering how to do it. If there is a block that can do this or some sort of sequence of events that can do this, please let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

If the 2 motors are configured as a drive base, use the pink **move** blocks.

For an arbitrary number of motors or non-drive-base cases, you can use **broadcast** blocks to run things in parallel. Here is an example that shows how to run 4 motors for a specific number of rotations:
[image: screenshot of scratch program]